# SQL server login limited to web application

Tags: c#, sql, iis, web-applications

What would be the best way to configure a web application and its SQL server to only login through the webapp itself, and not be able to use the same login through SQL Server management studio?
The case is that I'm currently developing a web application, and the application should have a dedicated account which also is limited to only this web application so it can't be used for interactive logon through other means.

Comment: Why not revoke all permissions for all users except the web application user and make sure the web application user does not have interactive permissions to the server?

Answer (score 1):

I use the same strategy for isolating the permissions on web applications.

I create a service account (meaning an account without interactive login privileges) and use it to run the application pool in IIS. Then I grant that account the needed permissions in SQL server for the database.